# Passing variable to $match causing Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators error

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to pass a variable to $match a specific record as shown in my code below under my Node.js app yet I am getting error "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators" so was wondering if someone can please assist by pointing out what I am missing / doing wrong here and how to solve it? Thanks

```
     let query = [];
     let filterCountry = 'United States';
     query.push(
        { '$lookup': { 
            'from': 'users', 
            'localField': 'userID', 
            'foreignField': '_id',
            'as': 'userData'  
        } },
        { '$unwind': '$userData' },
        { '$lookup': { 
            'from': 'categories', 
            'localField': 'categoryID', 
            'foreignField': '_id',
            'as': 'categoryData'  
        } });

        query.push({
            match: { 'userData.country': new RegExp(filterCountry, 'i') },                
        });

       query.push({ 
             $group: { _id: null, content: { $push: '$$ROOT' },count: { $sum: 1 } } }
       );
       const vendorsData = await Vendors.aggregate(query);
```

Taking in consideration that if I passed the country name directly, example:

```
        query.push({
            match: { 'userData.country': new RegExp('United States', 'i') },                
        });
```

it will work just fine.

Comment: You have to put some money first. Try it with `$match:{...}`

Comment: money solved it, thanks for your help. Please post your reply as an answer to accept it.

Comment: There are very few problem many can't solve =) Typo question are considered off topic. Glad my hint helped but there is no point to answer the question.